# Node Js Session user id

Tags: javascript

Hello I'm just new to Node.js and currently working on session login.

1. Why can't I set session inside my query function?
2. Why do I need `req.session.save()` to save it, but after redirecting to some page session its still not totally set and the page needs to refresh to show session.

Here is my function in setting session

```
client.query(
    "Select id FROM users Where username = '" + req.body.username + "' AND password = '" + req.body.password + "'",
    function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error('error running query', err);
        } else {
            done();
            req.session.user_id = result.rows;
            req.session.save();
            res.redirect('/wall');
        }
    });
```

Comment: **Danger!!**: Your code is wide open to [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/about)!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to simplify your example and clarify what libraries you are using. I am assuming you are using express and express-session. I set up a simple example where when you go to to /login?username=yourname page it redirects you to a different page where it shows your name.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var session = require('express-session');
var mysql = require('mysql')

app.use(session({secret: 'super secret'}));

var client = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "My",
    user: "private",
    password: "configuration",
    database: "my_db"
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    var sessionData = req.session;
    client.query('SELECT * from users where username = ?', [req.query.username], function(err, rows) {
        if(err) throw err;
        if (rows.length) {
            var user = rows[0]
            req.session.username = user.username;
            req.session.user_id = user.id
            res.redirect('/signed_in');
        } else {
            res.send("user not found")
        }
    })
})

app.get('/signed_in', function(req, res){
    res.send(req.session.user_id + "," + req.session.username);
});

http.listen(3000);
```

Quentin is right you should look out for sql injections. in the case of node you typically do something like this, depending on what sql library you are using.

```
client.query(
    "Select id FROM users Where username = ? AND password = ?", [req.body.username, req.body.password],
    function(err, result) {
    // Your code
}
```

As for why you have to refresh the page after you reload it my guess is something related to done function since i don't know what it is doing in your code. I have no idea why you need to call save, it is not necessary in my example.